# Any ideas on how to call serverless shell comand from another nodejs script

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to call serverless command like

```
serverless invoke local -f hello
```

but from another nodejs script.
I test it using node child_process spawn

```
const {spawn} = require ('child_process');
const cmd = 'serverless invoke local -f hello';
const p = spawn (cmd, [], {shell: true});

p.stdout.on ('data', (data) => {
    console.log (data.toString ());
});
```

or using exec

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function main() {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('serverless invoke local -f hello');

    if (stderr) {
        console.error(`error: ${stderr}`);
    }
    console.log(`${stdout}`);
}

main()
```

When I run both solutions from my terminal as

> node myscript.js

I can't get any response, any suggestions or ideas on how to do this will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const child = spawnSync('serverless', ['invoke', 'local', '-f', 'hello'])

console.log(child.output.toString('utf8'))
```

response:

```
,{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\n  \"message\": \"Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!\",\n  \"input\": \"\"\n}"
}
,
```